# Как сохранять куки после закрытия броузера?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, cookie

Как сделать так, чтобы куки сохранялись после закрытия броузера? То есть, чтобы после входа в броузер через пару дней, клиент не должен был снова набирать пароль. И можно ли программно изменять session-timeout, который установлен в web.xml?
В web.xml стоит так:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Вот нашла функцию, похоже она настраивает куки. Что тут надо исправить, чтобы скажем куки работали до следующего дня?

```
$.cookie = function(key, value, options) {

    // key and at least value given, set cookie...
    if (arguments.length > 1 && (!/Object/.test(Object.prototype.toString.call(value)) || value == null)) {
        options = $.extend({}, $.cookie.defaults, options);

        if (value == null) {
            options.expires = -1;
        }

        if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
            var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
            t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
        }

        value = String(value);

        return (document.cookie = [
            encodeURIComponent(key), '=', options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
            options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
            options.path    ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
            options.domain  ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
            options.secure  ? '; secure' : ''
        ].join(''));
    }

    // key and possibly options given, get cookie...
    options = value || $.cookie.defaults || {};
    var decode = options.raw ? raw : decoded;
    var cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
    for (var i = 0, parts; (parts = cookies[i] && cookies[i].split('=')); i++) {
        if (decode(parts.shift()) === key) {
            return decode(parts.join('='));
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```

Вызывается она так:
    $.cookie.defaults = {};

Answer (score 1):

В файле web.xml храниться параметр, отвечающий за время жизни сессии, а не COOKIE.

Вам нужно определить что именно на портале формирует COOKIE для прохождения авторизации. Возможно разработчики вписали время жизни куки хардкодом. Чтобы понять куда копать дальше нужно узнать время жизни той куки, которая авторизует, например, посмотрев в chrome список кук сайта. Возможно в настройках самого портала есть параметр, отвечающий за время жизни куки.

**UPD:**

`options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE` Эта строка в коде очень напоминает данные по Expire=)

[По материалам](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) вики (раздел Атрибуты куки) понятно, что формат параметра `expires` должен быть типа такого: `Fri, 31 Dec 2010 23:59:59 GMT`. Если Вы хотите быстро решить задачу - формируйте свою метку времени и вставляйте вместо `Fri, 31 Dec 2010 23:59:59 GMT`.

Но сразу обращу Ваше внимание на то, что этот способ неприемлем! Хардкод в проекте - жутка вещь, и пусть все кто так думает поставит **+** этому ответу)))

Comment: Посмотрела, там стоит: до конца сессии. А как это настраивается вообще? Где мне искать?

Comment: Без дополнительной информации никто помочь не сможет... У вас ведь Tomcat? Какое приложение работает на нем?

Comment: Да, Tomcat. Приложение написано на java + Spring. Какая нужна дополнительная инфа?

Comment: Вот нашла код по имени куки:         appletsource += '<param name="cookie" value="JSESSIONID=${pageContext.session.id}">\n';

Comment: Насколько понимаю, сюда надо еще expires как-то добавить?

Comment: Видимо эта кука настраивается через аплет. Какой тогда должен быть код в этом аплете? JSESSIONID - это ее имя.

Comment: На этот вопрос может ответить только разработчик системы, или документация, которая обычно идет в комплекте. Но самой в исходный код лезть не советую

Comment: Попробовала заменить на  appletsource += '<param name="cookie" value="JSESSIONID=${pageContext.session.id}; expires=Wed, 27 Mai 2015 14:00:00 GMT";>\n';   не изменилось ничего. Я теперь буду разработчик. А предыдущий ушел. Вот пытаюсь разобраться.

Comment: ";" перед >\n убрала. Все равно не работает.

Comment: К сожалению я не могу ответить на Ваш вопрос, возможно Вам стоит изменить вопрос с приведением части кода.

Comment: В этот appletsource заносятся еще кча параметров и он используется так: document.getElementById('appletdiv').innerHTML = appletsource; Может нужно эту фуркцию полностью привести?

Comment: Я пока не понимаю как `document.getElementById('appletdiv').innerHTML` связан со временем жизни куки. Или вопрос ушел в другое русло???

Comment: Тут не позволяет поле такой длинный комент, но если надо, я могу частями.

Comment: нет, русло то же самое, я только не знаю, где искать. Проект гигантский, вот нашла про куки, но как теперь понимаю, это не то, что мне надо. Что это должно вообще быть?

Comment: Может вот это больше подходит?   return (document.cookie = [
    encodeURIComponent(key), '=', options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
    options.expires ? '; expires=     options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', 
    options.path    ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
    options.domain  ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
    options.secure  ? '; secure' : ''
   ].join(''));

Comment: Внесла код функции, в которой предположительно должна настраиваться кука, в вопрос вверху. Посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: Обновил свой ответ.

Comment: Я написала так: return (document.cookie = [
    encodeURIComponent(key), '=', options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
    options.expires ? '; expires=Fri, 21 Jan 2021 06:10:00 GMT;' : '', 
    options.path    ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
    options.domain  ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
    options.secure  ? '; secure' : ''
   ].join('')); Но все равно получаю куки до конца сессии. Что неправильно?